# GraphQL with DynamoDB resolvers - one to many relationship solution

Tags: javascript, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, graphql-js

I'm going through a steep learning curve of learning DynamoDB design and applying it in practice using GraphQL. I came across a from the first glance a trivial problem but let me elaborate.

It's a simple relationship between questions and answers, a single question can have multiple answers which gives us a classic example of one-to-many relationship.

I have a GraphQL schema which looks like this: (unnecessary bits left out to keep it simple)

**Question schema**

```
    extend type Query {
        question (ID: ID!): Question
    }

    type Question {
        ID: ID!
        RecordType: String!
        value: String!
        answers: [Answer!]
    }
```

**Answer schema**

```
    extend type Query {
        answers(QUE_ID: ID!): [Answer!]
    }

    type Answer {
        ID: ID!
        RecordType: String!
        value: String!
    }
```

The DynamoDB design is this:

[image]

Where:

- First column: ID
- Second column: RecordType
- Third column: value

I also have two resolvers:
**Answer resolver**

```or-tag-here
Query: {
        answers: async (parent, { QUE_ID }, { dataSources }) => {
            try {
                const args = {
                    KeyConditionExpression: "ID=:id and begins_with(RecordType, :rtype)",
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ":id": QUE_ID,
                        ":rtype": "AR_ANS"
                    }
                };

                return await dataSources.questoSource.query(args);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question resolver**

```or-tag-here
Query: {
        question: async (parent, { ID }, { dataSources }) => {
            try {
                // get question from the db
                const question = await dataSources.questoSource.getRecord({
                    ID,
                    RecordType: `${process.env.QUESTION_PREFIX}`
                });

                // get question's answers from the db
                const args = {
                    KeyConditionExpression: "ID=:id and begins_with(RecordType, :rtype)",
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ":id": ID,
                        ":rtype": "AR_ANS"
                    }
                };

                const answers = await dataSources.questoSource.query(args);

                // combine answers with the question from the first db query
                question.answers = answers.Items;

                // return the result
                return question;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    },
```

Let's focus on the question resolver. As you can see, it fetches the question by ID, and then it gets the answers to the question, combines them and returns.
It's also obvious, when you look at both resolvers that Question resolver, uses exactly the same piece of code as the Answer resolver.

**Question number one**

***How can I reuse code between resolvers so that instead of writing the same code twice, I just import the Answer resolver to the Question resolver and run the DB query. Shall I just extract the db logic to a separate component and reuse the component and keep the resolvers separate?***

**Question number two**

DynamoDB design shown in the table above, allows to query Questions with all its Answers in one go by querying the db records by ID. If I query all the records with `ID=QUE_1` I will also get all the answers.
The problem here is that I would have to do some pretty extensive mapping/reducing on the javascript side to make the data model as GraphQL schema expects it.
***Is this approach efficient? It seems to me, it's better to query DynamoDB twice, than write less mentionable code.***